# BLE not reading characteristic in reactive_ble

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I'm using the flutter_reactive_ble package to communicate with a ble device. All is good until I try to read the characteristic which gives me the following error:

```
E/flutter (28251): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: GenericFailure<CharacteristicValueUpdateError>(code: CharacteristicValueUpdateError.unknown, message: "GATT exception from MAC address EE:2F:27:FE:D2:44, with type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}")
```

This is my code block that contains the function:

```
Uuid _UART_UUID = Uuid.parse("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
Uuid _UART_RX = Uuid.parse("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
Uuid _UART_TX = Uuid.parse("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");  

case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          {
            _connected = true;
            _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Connected to $id\n";
            _numberOfMessagesReceived = 0;
            _receivedData = [];

            //READ
            final _rxCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
              serviceId: _UART_UUID,
              characteristicId: _UART_RX,
              deviceId: event.deviceId,
            );
            try {
              final _charResponse =
                  flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(_rxCharacteristic);
              print(_charResponse);
            } catch (e) {
              print("COULDN'T READ CHARACTERISTIC $e");
            }

            break;
          }
```

I already tried finding other characteristic uuids to see if the problem was about the uuid, but no luck. I've been using nRF Connect to check on some parameters. The uuids I found there are the ones I'm using currently.
I have Nordic UART Service as a primary service and I have the following:

- Nordic UART Service '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'

  - Rx Characteristic '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
    -'WRITE, WRITE NO RESPONSE'
  - Tx Characteristic '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
    -'NOTIFY'

How can I fix this and sucessfully read the characteristics I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread the documentation. The *Rx Characteristic* is the *Rx Characteristic* of the device you are connected to. You are only allowed to `write` to this characteristic, which sends data to the connected device.
Data send from the connected device to your application is delivered via the `Notify` of the *Tx Characteristic*

Comment: So I should only try to write to that Rx Characteristic and then the device returns what I need?

Comment: Yes, via the `Notify` of the Tx Characteristic.